# Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes - Container stuck in ContainerCreating state

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, local-storage, storage

I have a brand new 3-nodes cluster all ubuntu 22.04 up and running and working fine until I started playing with storage.
I created another ubuntu box and added nfs-kernel-server, then nfs-common on all 3 nodes.

I tested from the 3 nodes on commandline with

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 c1-storage:/export/volumes /mnt/
```

and it works fine, however, I created a PersistentVolume as well as a PersistentVolumeClaim pointing to it, when I issue

```
kubectl get PersistentVolume pv-nfs-data
```

I get which seems OK

```
NAME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                  STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pv-nfs-data   10Gi       RWX            Retain           Bound    default/pvc-nfs-data                           133m
```

I issue

```
kubectl get PersistentVolumeClaim pvc-nfs-data
```

I get

```
NAME           STATUS   VOLUME        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc-nfs-data   Bound    pv-nfs-data   10Gi       RWX                           129m
```

However, when I run a Pod with the following spec

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-nfs-deployment
spec:  
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: webcontent
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-nfs-data
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: webcontent
          mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html/web-app"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-nfs-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

but Pod is stuck, when I issue

```
kubectl get pods
```

> nginx-nfs-deployment-b69b64f9b-ppvrl 0/1 ContainerCreating 0 34m

I do a describe, I see a timeout, aiting for the condition

```
kubectl describe pod nginx-nfs-deployment-b69b64f9b-ppvrl
Name:             nginx-nfs-deployment-b69b64f9b-ppvrl
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             kubernetes/192.168.1.31
Start Time:       Wed, 22 Mar 2023 17:11:29 +0000
Labels:           app=nginx
                  pod-template-hash=b69b64f9b
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:
IPs:              <none>
Controlled By:    ReplicaSet/nginx-nfs-deployment-b69b64f9b
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /usr/share/nginx/html/web-app from webcontent (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n8wzr (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  webcontent:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pvc-nfs-data
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-n8wzr:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    35m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx-nfs-deployment-b69b64f9b-ppvrl to kubernetes
  Warning  FailedMount  3m36s (x8 over 30m)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[webcontent], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-n8wzr webcontent]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  79s (x7 over 33m)    kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[webcontent], unattached volumes=[webcontent kube-api-access-n8wzr]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  52s (x10 over 32m)   kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv-nfs-data" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t nfs 172.16.94.5:/export/volumes/pod /var/lib/kubelet/pods/574230b8-ce87-46df-8e0c-a7c243d7e228/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pv-nfs-data
Output: mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

So why on commandline it works fine, storage is mounted according to Kubernets but Pod is stuck, knowing that firewalls are disabled on all boxes? How to troubleshoot this and what can be the issue? Thanks

Here is the output of df -h

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              577M  2.2M  575M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   23G   18G  4.0G  82% /
tmpfs                              2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  265M  1.6G  15% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              577M  116K  577M   1% /run/user/123
tmpfs                              577M  144K  577M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                              5.6G   12K  5.6G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5a8b7d33-ce31-4e92-8848-113809bcda93/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-7qlb7
tmpfs                              5.6G   12K  5.6G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5107746e-c738-455c-a88d-dd4644fd551d/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-qzrb2
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/03f66b36bc72dd3e05c1d8e8bd1968d57f1f9be22e17a336d07eebae04aa6e6f/shm
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/ac99cf0e46638550e212c789b4c548ccf87095e63d36b5fae739e27f19289f34/shm
overlay                             23G   18G  4.0G  82% /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/ac99cf0e46638550e212c789b4c548ccf87095e63d36b5fae739e27f19289f34/rootfs
overlay                             23G   18G  4.0G  82% /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/03f66b36bc72dd3e05c1d8e8bd1968d57f1f9be22e17a336d07eebae04aa6e6f/rootfs
overlay                             23G   18G  4.0G  82% /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d36907a7ec8c705fdb7b18651fe9ce877a83eec0d7f17b4b5d8151e24640d675/rootfs
overlay                             23G   18G  4.0G  82% /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/0acbdfe6d6f9d2184eecfc3c9884bdbfe24bca8e349e840b39e233185435aa14/rootfs
tmpfs                              5.6G   12K  5.6G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/54621eb4-afff-4534-99d6-cea9dc222784/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-rs48h
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/d46126ffb1566e9a760969ca0b69eaa800fa7b6bd62a5b67694e1dfdca3ab621/shm
overlay                             23G   18G  4.0G  82% /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d46126ffb1566e9a760969ca0b69eaa800fa7b6bd62a5b67694e1dfdca3ab621/rootfs
overlay                             23G   18G  4.0G  82% /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/0d6af12e6e789e6ed3bf294d0063bf5f94b882da4618aeebca9d13af0b53dc57/rootfs
tmpfs                              5.6G   12K  5.6G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/574230b8-ce87-46df-8e0c-a7c243d7e228/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-n8wzr
```

Here are the yaml file for the PV and PVC

**PV**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.1.36
    path: "/export/volumes/pod"
```

**- PVC**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-nfs-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Outpout for

> kubectl get po -A

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                          READY   STATUS              RESTARTS        AGE
default                hello-world-nodeport-6dd9d7c5f9-n82qw         1/1     Running             0               10h
default                hello-world-service-blue-7dd9564-zcjpn        1/1     Running             0               3d2h
default                hello-world-service-red-79bc8df4cc-ps4zs      1/1     Running             0               3d2h
default                hello-world-service-single-6b576f46dd-cwgvv   1/1     Running             0               3d2h
default                hello-world-service-single-6b576f46dd-sbkpr   1/1     Running             0               3d11h
default                nginx-nfs-deployment-b69b64f9b-2llbd          0/1     ContainerCreating   0               7m4s
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller-54d878c797-qmbcj     1/1     Running             0               3d2h
kube-system            calico-kube-controllers-56dd5794f-bnv6x       1/1     Running             15 (21h ago)    29d
kube-system            calico-node-8dsgx                             1/1     Running             13 (10h ago)    29d
kube-system            calico-node-jd9b7                             1/1     Running             6 (3d2h ago)    23d
kube-system            calico-node-tc5x2                             1/1     Running             9 (21h ago)     29d
kube-system            coredns-787d4945fb-49skm                      1/1     Running             9 (21h ago)     29d
kube-system            coredns-787d4945fb-ftjpj                      1/1     Running             9 (21h ago)     29d
kube-system            etcd-kubernetes2                              1/1     Running             11 (21h ago)    29d
kube-system            kube-apiserver-kubernetes2                    1/1     Running             16 (21h ago)    29d
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-kubernetes2           1/1     Running             34 (21h ago)    29d
kube-system            kube-proxy-7n9nh                              1/1     Running             11 (21h ago)    29d
kube-system            kube-proxy-snctn                              1/1     Running             35 (3d3h ago)   23d
kube-system            kube-proxy-tk88r                              1/1     Running             9 (10h ago)     29d
kube-system            kube-scheduler-kubernetes2                    1/1     Running             36 (21h ago)    29d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-7bc864c59-g92hx     1/1     Running             0               3d11h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-6c7ccbcf87-s9nbz         1/1     Running             0               3d11h
```

Following Michal recommandation, I created Praqma/Network-Multitool pod, issued the command telnet and Pod was able to telnet, here is the ouput

[image]

Calico Pod log
[image]

Comment: can you update your question with the output of `df -h` command on the node (`kubernetes/192.168.1.31`)where the pod is scheduled?

Comment: Hello, here is the output

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75815752/edit) your question and paste all the output there. you can delete your comments as it's impossible to read

Comment: I did, output of dh -f is in the initial question

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you `PVC` is not referring to any `StorageClass` and since you are using `NFS` you should handle it a little bit different than standard storage.

Please check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#nfs) section of `k8s` documentation where you can find information about need of creating proper `StorageClass` and also installing `NFS` provisioner like [NFS Ganesha Server and Volume Provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-ganesha-server-and-external-provisioner) or [Dynamic sub-dir volume provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner).

Comment: Michal, I understand that Storage class is optional. I am watching an education "Kubernetes Configuring Managing Storage and Scheduling" on pluralsight where in the demos usimng the exact same yaml files for pv and pvc and everything runs fine without the need toi a storageclass? Is this wrong then?

Comment: I will update my question wit the yaml files for both pv and pvc

Comment: Pluralsight is providing you some demo environment? If yes could you check what is the output of following commands `kubectl get sc` and `kubectl get po -A`?
I have a feeling that demo cluster can have some thing pre-install and that is why it is working there.

Comment: I will update my question with the ouput of kubectl get po -A. In the error message when I do describe pod, I see Mounting arguments: -t nfs 172.16.94.5:/export/volumes/pod /var/lib/kubelet/pods/3365154c,  the IP of the nfs file server is 192.168.1.36 and not 172.16.94.5  , should I install something somewhere in order to make pods use the real IP? not sure as this is the first time I use storgae mecanism

Comment: Also, Pluralsight does not provide an environment, it is the course instructor who provided sh files and code to create the environment, I can share with you the link to download it

Comment: As a debug step could you deploy some pod with `telnet` and check if command `telnet <<nfs dns name>> 2049` is working? If yes this will indicate that there is some problem with resource configuration like `PV`, `PVC` or `nfs` binaries. If no then there will be some network issue between your cluster and `nfs` server.

Comment: I created a pod based on Praqma/Network-Multitool, did issue the command you suggested and connection went through as follows                                                              salam@kubernetes2:~$ telnet 192.168.1.36 2049
Trying 192.168.1.36...
Connected to 192.168.1.36.
Escape character is '^]'.                      I will add a snapshot in the initial question so you can read it better

Comment: Michal, you say "problem with resource configuration like PV, PVC.....", I provided them up here, which both seems OK, regarding nfs, I followed and applied all necessary instructions and as I said, I can mount/unmout mounts from commandline from the nodes, again, I will as the same question as yesterday : Why In the error message when I do describe pod, I see Mounting arguments: -t nfs 172.16.94.5:/export/volumes/pod /var/lib/kubelet/pods/3365154c, the IP of the nfs file server is 192.168.1.36 and not 172.16.94.5

Comment: I was not precise in my last comment. Command `telnet <<nfs dns name>> 2049` should be run from pod deployed on cluster so it should be `kubectl exec -it network-multitool -- telnet 192.168.1.36 2049`.
Regarding IP it will be good to check `calico` pods logs since it looks like some issue with networking.

Comment: Michal, yes, I deployed a Pod using the network-multitool, I will update the screen shot in the question, sorry I have put the bad screennshot, as you will notice the ouput of kubectl exec -it  network-multitool -- telnet 192.168.1.36 2049 is good

Comment: Michal, I checked logs for calico on the 192.168.1.31 node 1, it seems OK except I can find 1 error                                                                                                                   
 2023-03-24 13:08:04.803 [INFO][88] confd/watchercache.go 125: Watch error received from Upstream ListRoot="/calico/ipam/v2/host/kubernetes" error=too old resource version: 677 (1772591), I will drop a screenshot aS WELL

Comment: Michal, let me hold a moment and as the following question : Should the NFS server be a pod inside the k8S cluster and not a distinct server not joined the cluster, but mainly on the same lan where the cluster is? I am a little bit confused after reading so many articles on the web

Comment: NFS server can be place outside of k8s. My experience with `nfs` and `k8s` is mostly Cloud base (AWS) and I was using `AWS EFS` as their implementation of `nfs`. But to be able to use some network storage I was always using some kind of provisioner and that is why I advise you to use one. I also saw some tutorials where there was no need to install provisioner but those are referring to `nfs` server on worker node or directly in `k8s`. If you want to connect to external `nfs` please do it with provisioner.

Comment: Michal, after searching and ivestigation where 172.16.94.5 came from, oh Mu God, my bad, I have changed the this IP by the right IP of the storage server on my local dev box but forgot to updat the one that ws on the master node, just updated it and Pod creation went through like a charm, sorry for all this confusion I created because of my mistake. So in this case we dont need a storage class. But through this error I learned a lot